# Equivalent Metrics on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am working on a problem and want to verify that my logic and reasoning is correct. This is my first time working with metric spaces.

> Show that the following define equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   \begin{eqnarray} 
> \varphi^*(x,y)&=&|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|\\
> \varphi^+(x,y)&=&\text{max}\{|x_1-y_1|,\cdots,|x_n-y_n|\} \end{eqnarray}

By definition, we know two metrics on a set are equivalent if there are two positive numbers, $c_1$ and $c_2$, such that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_1\cdot\varphi^*(x,y)\leq\varphi^+(x,y)\leq c_2\cdot\varphi^*(x,y).
\end{eqnarray*}

Claim 1: $c_1\cdot\varphi^*(x,y)\leq\varphi^+(x,y)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_1\cdot\varphi^*(x,y)&=&c_1[|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|]\\
&=&c_1|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+c_1|x_n-y_n|]
\end{eqnarray*}

Claim 2: $\varphi^+(x,y)\leq c_2\cdot\varphi^*(x,y)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_2\cdot\varphi^*(x,y)&=&c_2[|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+|x_n-y_n|]\\
&=&c_2|x_1-y_1|+\cdots+c_2|x_n-y_n|]
\end{eqnarray*}

**Questions:**

1. Is my reasoning sound so far?
2. Are $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{N}$, meaning they can't be fractions?
3. I know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a normed linear space. How does this fact help me specifically? I feel like this is the key in being able to finish proving my claims.

Comment: What number is $c_1$ in claim 1? You need to prove the existence of numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ that satisfy the required conditions. You can't leave $c_1$ unspecified. $c_1$ and $c_2$ need to be positive real numbers. They don't need to be natural numbers. In fact, $c_1$ will frequently have to be a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive numbers. So $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$. To make my statement true in claim 1. $c_1$ would have to be between 0 and 1. Right?

Comment: No. $c_1$ and $c_2$ need to be numbers you specify that satisfy the inequalities for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For example, if you could prove that $c_1 = 1/3$ and $c_2 = 5$ work, that would be a good answer. (I'm not saying these numbers actually work.) Why don't you start with the case $n = 3$?

Comment: The way you defined $\varphi^*$ and $\varphi^+$, they are the same function (as $\varphi^+$ is the maximum of a singleton set). Are you sure that $\varphi^+$ is defined correctly this way and not maybe $\varphi^+(x,y) = \max\{|x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|, \dots, |x_n - y_n| \}$?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch you are right. I made a typo. I will correct that in the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @David So all I need to do is show that is true for some $c_1$ and $c_2$? Just one example is enough to say they are equivalent?

Comment: One example of $c_1$ and one example of $c_2$, yes. But that doesn't mean it's simple: you need to prove that that choice of $c_1$ works for *all* choices of $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and similarly for $c_2$.

Comment: You do not have to find the maximal $c_1$, respectively the minimal $c_2\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, but only _any_ $c_1$ and $c_2$. However, for these two values, the inequalities have to hold for _all_ $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$. Note, that the values of $c_1$,$c_2$ might depend on the specific metric space you are looking at. In your example, they might e.g. depend on $n$ *hint*.

Comment: Engineer's hint that the answer depends on $n$ is correct. That's why I suggested you look first at $n = 3$. Here is the way to think about finding $c_2$. Say you already know what $\varphi^{*}(x,y)$ is. What is the largest that $\varphi^{+}(x,y)$ could possibly be?

Comment: I am sorry I am struggling with this concept so much. I tried $n=3$ with $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c_2=5$. I don't see how the inequality is coming in

Answer (score 1):

I will answer for $n = 2$. Then you can generalize to higher values of $n$. The argument is similar.

Given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, say I know $M = \phi^{*}(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|$. How large can $\phi^{+}(x,y) = \max(|x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|)$ be? The sum of the two nonnegative numbers $|x_1 - y_1|$ and $|x_2 - y_2|$ is $M$. Therefore, neither of the two numbers can exceed $M$. Hence the maximum of the two numbers does not exceed $M$. In other words, we have
$$\phi^{+}(x,y) \leq \phi^{*}(x,y).$$
This shows that the second inequality is satisfied for $c_2 = 1$.

Now say instead that I know $N = \phi^{+}(x,y) = \max(|x_1 - y_1|, |x_2 - y_2|)$. How large can $\phi^{*}(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|$ be? The quantity $\phi^{*}(x,y)$ is the sum of two numbers neither of which exceeds $N$. Therefore this sum is at most $2N$. Thus
$$\phi^{*}(x,y) \leq 2\phi^{+}(x,y).$$
This shows that the first inequality is satisfied for $c_1 = 1/2$.

To answer your questions:

1. No, your reasoning is incorrect. You need to say what $c_1$ and $c_2$ are and prove that they work.
2. The numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not necessarily whole numbers.
3. There is a theorem that says that any two norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent. If you are permitted to use this theorem, then the statement follows immediately from the fact that $\phi^{*}$ and $\phi^{+}$ are norms. However, if the purpose of the problem is to give a direct proof, then I don't see how this can be used to simplify the solution significantly.

Comment: Ok. So in the more general case $c_1=\frac{1}{n}$ and $c_2=1$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it.